# How to render directly on a 3D texture efficiently in threejs / webgl?

Tags: three.js, 3d, webgl

I'm currently working on a fluid simulation. I am working in 3D and so are the inputs and outputs. Each shader takes one or more 3D samples and should ideally output 3D data.

Currently, I'm slicing the 3D cube and running the shader on each plane. This method works but then I need to copy the data from each 2D texture to the CPU to reconstruct a 3D texture and send it back to the GPU. The copying step is terribly slow and I think this method is not optimal.

```js
const vertexShaderPlane = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

in vec3 position;

out vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
    vPosition = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position.xy, 0., 1. );
}
`

const fragmentShaderPlane = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp sampler3D;

uniform float uZ;
    
in vec3 vPosition;

out vec4 out_FragColor;
    
void main() {
    out_FragColor = vec4(vPosition.xy, uZ, 1.);
}`

const vertexShaderCube = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

in vec3 position;

out vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
    vPosition = position;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
`

const fragmentShaderCube = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp sampler3D;

uniform sampler3D sBuffer;

in vec3 vPosition;

out vec4 out_FragColor;
    
void main() {
    vec4 data = texture(sBuffer, vec3(vPosition));

    out_FragColor = vec4(data);
}
`

const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { alpha: false, antialias: false })

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, context })

const cameras = {
  perspective: new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 50000),
  texture: new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0, 1)
}

renderer.autoClear = false
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

// cameras.perspective.position.set(2, 2, 2)

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

// Uniforms

const planeUniforms = { uZ: { value: 0.0 } }
const cubeUniforms = { sBuffer: { value: null } }

// Plane (2D)

const materialPlane = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: planeUniforms,
  vertexShader: vertexShaderPlane,
  fragmentShader: fragmentShaderPlane,
  depthTest: true,
  depthWrite: true
})

const planeGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
const vertices = new Float32Array([
  0, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 0,
  1, 1, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, 0, 0
])
planeGeometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))

const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, materialPlane)
plane.position.set(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)
scene.add(plane)

// Cube (3D)

const materialCube = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: cubeUniforms,
  vertexShader: vertexShaderCube,
  fragmentShader: fragmentShaderCube,
  depthTest: true,
  depthWrite: true,
  visible: false
})

const cube = new THREE.Group()
for (let x = 0; x < 32; x++) {
  const offset = x / 32
  const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
  const vertices = new Float32Array([
    0, 0, offset,
    1, 0, offset,
    1, 1, offset,
    1, 1, offset,
    0, 1, offset,
    0, 0, offset
  ])
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3))
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialCube)
  cube.add(mesh)
}

cube.position.set(-0.5, 0, -2)
cube.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
cube.rotation.set(1, 1, 1)
scene.add(cube)

// Computing Step

const texture2D = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(32, 32, { type: THREE.FloatType })
const planeSize = (32 ** 2 * 4)
const pixelBuffers = Array.from(Array(32), () => new Float32Array(planeSize))

const data = new Float32Array(planeSize * 32)
renderer.setRenderTarget(texture2D)
for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  materialPlane.uniforms.uZ.value = i / 32

  renderer.render(scene, cameras.texture)

  renderer.readRenderTargetPixels(texture2D, 0, 0, 32, 32, pixelBuffers[i]) // SLOW PART
  data.set(pixelBuffers[i], i * planeSize)
}

const texture3D = new THREE.DataTexture3D(data, 32, 32, 32)
texture3D.format = THREE.RGBAFormat
texture3D.type = THREE.FloatType
texture3D.unpackAlignment = 1

materialPlane.visible = false

// Display Step

materialCube.visible = true
cubeUniforms.sBuffer.value = texture3D
renderer.setRenderTarget(null)
renderer.render(scene, cameras.perspective)
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

I emphasize that the rendering **works**. It's just **extremely slow** because I have to execute a dozen shaders.

The potential solutions I found are the following:

- Use the `render.copyFramebufferToTexture` function to copy the data directly into a new texture. Unfortunately I think it only works for 2D and not 3D textures.
- Use web workers to split the task and render a plan per worker. However, to pass the data to the workers you have to copy them, which comes back to the initial problem. Transferring the data wouldn't be efficient either because while one worker would do his job the others wouldn't have access to the data.

**EDIT:**

I'm just looking for a way to speed up the process of copying 2D data to the CPU to make a 3D texture back on the GPU.

The real issue is `renderer.readRenderTargetPixels` that really slow down my render.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for taking the tour! Would it be possible to simplify your code into a smaller running example? I understand your goal might be to use large data sets, but getting it working in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Short non-detailed answer: You can't render directly to a 3D texture. But you can simplify a 3D texture into a 2D texture by smartly layering each slice side by side. This means you'll have an extra overhead for computing the texture coordinates, but at least you can input and output a faux-3DTexture.

Comment: This is how this sort of thing is usually done in WebGL. It's worth mentioning that you need to be mindful about the texture sampling caveats, linear sampling on the slice boundaries WILL return bad data. Because you are interpolating two texels that have no spatial relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ScieCode mentioned, you can't write to a 3D texture in WebGL/WebGL2 but you can use a 2D texture as 3D data. Imagine we have a 4x4x4 3D texture. We can store that in a 2D texture. That's 4 slices of 4x4. We might arrange those slices

```
00001111
00001111
00001111
00001111
22223333
22223333
22223333
22223333
```

To get a pixel from that 2D texture being used as 3D data

```
   ivec3 src = ...              // some 3D coord
   int cubeSize = 4;            // could pass in as uniform
   ivec2 slices = size / cubeSize;
   ivec2 size = textureSize(some2DSampler, 0);
   ivec2 src2D = ivec2(
      src.x + (src.z % slices.x) * cubeSize,
      src.y + (src.z / slices.x) * cubeSize);
   vec4 color = texelFetch(some2DSampler, src2D, 0);
```

If we render a single quad across the entire texture we know which pixel is currently being written in 3D with

```
  // assume size is the same as the texture above, otherwise pass it in
  // as a uniform

  int cubeSize = 4;            // could pass in as uniform
  ivec2 slices = size / cubeSize;
  ivec2 dst2D = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
  ivec3 dst = ivec3(
      dst2D.x % cubeSize,
      dst2D.y % cubeSize,
      dst2D.x / cubeSize + (dst2D.y / cubeSize) * slices.x);
```

the code above assumes a each dimension of the cube is the same size. Something more generic, say we had a 5x4x6 cube. We might lay that out as as 3x2 slices

```
000001111122222
000001111122222
000001111122222
000001111122222
333334444455555
333334444455555
333334444455555
333334444455555
```

```
   ivec3 src = ...                   // some 3D coord
   ivec3 cubeSize = ivec3(5, 4, 6);  // could pass in as uniform
   ivec2 size = textureSize(some2DSampler, 0);
   int slicesAcross = size.x / cubeSize.x; 
   ivec2 src2D = ivec2(
      src.x + (src.z % slicesAcross) * cubeSize,
      src.y + (src.z / slicesAcross) * cubeSize);
   vec4 color = texelFetch(some2DSampler, src2D, 0);
```

```
  ivec3 cubeSize = ivec3(5, 4, 6);  // could pass in as uniform
  ivec2 slicesAcross = size.x / cubeSize;
  ivec2 dst2D = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
  ivec3 dst = ivec3(
      dst2D.x % cubeSize.x,
      dst2D.y % cubeSize.y,
      dst2D.x / cubeSize.x + (dst2D.y / cubeSize.y) * slicesAcross);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I've tried this technique before and I ran into several problems. 
I need to have a dynamic resolution and this is getting really hard to handle; 
By doing it like this I'm limited in texture size, 128x128 per slice I think. 
And finally the data at the edges are interpolated while they are not spatially next to each other. 
This may be a solution but it doesn't meet my expectations.

Comment: Assuming your max texture size is 16384, you are only limited to 128x128 slices if you are only arranging slices in one axis. If you arranging them in both x,y axis, you can get away with 655x655 slices.

Comment: As far as the data interpolation at the slices boundaries, you just have to clamp the texture sample coordinates to at most the center of the edge texels. It adds overhead, but nothing even comparable to your current solution. As I said, this is how people deal with 3D textures. I'm afraid it doesn't get much better than this.

Comment: there is no interpolation with `texelFetch`. If you mean your cube texture coordnates go outside the range of the cube then just add `clamp` statements to clamp the coordinates. Also the code above handles dynamic resolutions.

Comment: Thank you, so I will try this solution again with your advice, it seems to be the best solution to improve the temporal complexity.